# How to enable/disable a Button view of outer class from inner class in Android Studio with Java?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

The code I tried:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    private class xyz{

        MainActivity.button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

But here it shows an error and says, **cannot resolve symbol 'setEnabled'**. Normally it should recognize **setEnabled**.
Now, How can I solve this issue?
My XML code is also given for your consideration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xyz"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please mention your usecase what you trying to achieve here. Ideally its not recommended to hold a static reference of any of your Views.

Comment: I just want to enable or disable the Button view from the inner class which was declared in the outer class. I also tried instantiating an object of MainActivity, but that didn't work either.

Comment: rebuild and run your code,hope will work.@RAWNAKYAZDANI

Comment: @androidLearner It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very good question
you have many option to do it, but ill give you two example:
first one create a contractor for class xyz

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      static Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
    private class xyz{
        xyz() {
            MainActivity.button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

second way is to avoid using  static

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        
    }
    private class xyz{
        Button btn;
        xyz() {
            btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also I strongly suggest using view binding

Comment: The codes you have given will work only if an inner class object is instantiated in the outer class which you did not include in your code (only then the constructor will be called). Is there another way to do it without using the constructor? Also, as you said, how can we do it using **view binding**? Whould you provide the code?

Comment: if you can give me the case of using this setEnabled(false); , I can help you more.
and for view binding is just a way  to avoid findviewbyid() and more safer for NullPointerException. in the android documentation, the have a code example of using it.

Comment: Suppose I am checking a license in the inner class and want to disable the button when the license is not valid.

Comment: in the inner class you can refer to the button by findViewById(R.id.button), in constructor or in any method. but the question when you will create an object of xyz.

Comment: I think I have got my answer to this specific question. Thanks for answering.